# What do you call a person who acts as a substitute for all in a team?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have always found myself being “[jack of all trades](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/jack-of-all-trades) “in skills in a team and able to fill in for some of the experienced ones when they are away.

I can't think of a word to describe me.

I always like being the balance keeper in a team, if I witness we are lacking in something say, X. I will start taking the role for X (just having average skill in X).

Is it common to use the expression “jack of all trades“ in the context described  above, if not what expression is more appropriate?

Comment: Please edit your post to show us which words you've already considered but discarded, along with why you found each of those unsuitable.